# Movie involving a samurai's ghost and a courtroom scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I remember partially watching a movie on an airplane. It was about a woman who is able to see the ghost of a Samurai or some other warrior who was beheaded, I think falsely for being a traitor. Anyways, I think the woman and the ghost set out to do...something. I don't remember, but I think it was to clear his name?

Anyways, along the way, the woman meets another man who is outwardly extremely skeptical about the supernatural and says that there must always be a trick involved somewhere where the supernatural is apparently at play. The woman figures out that the man is actually capable of seeing the ghost, and theorizes that it is because the man's favorite Indian dish contains cinnamon, which is connected to the spirit world.

Anyways, eventually the woman and the ghost figure out that the ghost would be able to send messages to the material world by interacting with a small object that the woman holds between her fingers. If I recall correctly, it was shaped like or is a Lifesaver candy. Eventually, there is a scene in a courtroom where the woman and the ghost use the communication trick to enable the ghost to respond to yes/no questions.

Then, the man starts going on a monologue towards the other people present, while the ghost talks over him. Eventually, the man yells at the ghost to shut up, revealing to everyone that he can see and hear the ghost. I don't remember anything else from the movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[A Ghost of a Chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Ghost_of_a_Chance)*** (2011).

> *A Ghost of a Chance* (ステキな金縛り, *Suteki na Kanashibari*) (also known as "Once In a Blue Moon" in Japan) is a 2011 Japanese comedy mystery film directed by Kōki Mitani.

> Emi Hosho, a third-rate lawyer without much of a future, is tasked with defending Goro Yabe, a man arrested for the murder of his wife. Without much hope of winning, Yabe proclaims his innocence, saying that he was under sleep paralysis at the time of the murder. **Emi heads to the inn where Yabe stayed and encounters the ghost of fallen samurai Rokubei Sarashina, who claims he was the one holding Yabe in sleep paralysis. Rokubei is brought to the court as a witness. However, the prosecution denies the existence of the occult, asserting that Rokubei's testimony is inadmissible in court.** So begins the struggle to prove Yabe's innocence.

As noted in the Wikipedia plot summary, the woman is a defence lawyer who calls upon the ghost to stand as a witness in a court trial, to prove another man innocent of murdering his wife.

Since most people can't see the ghost or hear him speak, the woman initially attempts to serve an interpreter for him, repeating his testimony before the court. However, the Judge seems unsatisfied with this, and asks whether or not a direct utterance can be heard from the ghost himself. She then remembers that the ghost's breath can be felt in the physical world when he blows on things, and deduces that by holding a Lifesaver-like candy in front of his mouth, he can use it as a whistle to answer 'yes' or 'no' questions in a way that can be heard by everyone.

The ghost also notices the lawyer for the prosecution looking directly at him at one point, and realising that this man can also see and hear him (despite pretending to be sceptical about the existence of ghosts), he deliberately talks over the man incessantly in one scene, until the man gets so angry that he forgets himself for a moment and tells the ghost to shut up in front of the entire courtroom.

Comment: I'm intrigued how the banana fits into this courtroom drama. Murder weapon? Her lunch?

Comment: About five minutes into the film, the defence lawyer uses it as a prop in an attempt to cast doubt on eyesight of a witness for the prosecution (who said he saw the defendant fleeing the scene of the crime). She briefly shows him the banana from several metres away, and then hides it behind her back, hoping he'll fail to correctly identify what it was. Oddly enough though, this plan doesn't bear fruit.

Comment: Maybe she was plantain the seeds of doubt

Comment: She probably figured that if all else failed, she could eventually win on a peel.

Comment: As long as she doesn't slip up.